# Does Islam allow a Muslim female to marry a non muslim?

Tags: nikah

Is is allowed in Islam that if a Muslim female marry a non-Muslim man

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, Islam does not allow a Muslim women to marry non-Muslim man and vice-versa. Until He/She accepts Islam

Comment: Do you have any evidence supporting your claims?

Comment: And do not marry polytheistic women until they believe. And a believing slave woman is better than a polytheist, even though she might please you. And do not marry polytheistic men [to your women] until they believe. And a believing slave is better than a polytheist, even though he might please you. Those invite [you] to the Fire, but Allah invites to Paradise and to forgiveness, by His permission. And He makes clear His verses to the people that perhaps they may remember.

[QURAN 2:221]

Comment: "This day [all] good foods have been made lawful, and the food of those who were given the Scripture is lawful for you and your food is lawful for them. And [lawful in marriage are] chaste women from among the believers and chaste women from among those who were given the Scripture before you, when you have given them their due compensation, desiring chastity, not unlawful sexual intercourse or taking [secret] lovers. And whoever denies the faith - his work has become worthless, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers." (5:5)

Comment: Just taking one ayah randomly is not going to help u, u have to understand the whole context.

Comment: Most ulema's agrees that it is not permissible for a Muslim women/man to marry non-Muslim. They are not talking in air, they are the peoples who have spent whole life leading Quran and Hadith. Who are we to challenge them.

Comment: This verse is according the majority among the last revelations and except with Ibn 'Omar no scholar holds the opinion that verse 2:221 counts when it comes to marrying a non-Muslim woman. While at-Tabari actually narrated the opposite from 'Omar ibn al-Khattab.